# Azure SDK needed on on-premises server?

Tags: windows, azure-servicebusrelay

I'm looking at exposing a WCF-service through Azure ServiceBus Relay. The service is running on IIS (Windows Server 2008 R2) on-premises.

In the samples and documentation I've found, it says that the Azure SDK is needed on the server. That is for the relay-bindings I suppose.

But is really all of the SDK needed? When I install it (Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) -2.2), it installs Visual Studio Express etc. Is there no way to install support for ServiceBus Relay on the server, without getting these "extra" components that I really don't need on the production server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the [Windows Azure Service Bus](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) nuget package.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I realized that when looking at the needed dlls.